# Why isn't Heroku part of the Rails ecosystem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

Is there a particular reason for which [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) isn't officially part of the [Rails ecosystem](http://rubyonrails.org/ecosystem)?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you specifically mean the Heroku deployment mechanism? The Heroku database mechanism (Heroku completely ignores whatever you have in your production database.yml file)? The readonly copy of your app? Heroku has a lot of technologies in their platform.

Comment: Mostly the deployment, because my question is: why isn't Heroku listed in the Hosting section in Rails' ecosystem page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because Heroku hasn't been around for that long, and that page hasn't been updated recently. If Heroku's absence is brought to the webmaster's attention, I'm sure Heroku will be added.

Comment: It's currently listed (at the Hosting section).